# jQuery AJAX Hitting Error

Tags: json, jquery

This should be pretty simple, I can't figure out whey my ajax code keeps saying there is an error.

The data sends fine to the server, there are no errors on the server, it returns the expected results, but hits the 'error:' function every time.

Someone please help this is really anoying me :(

```
var sendData = new Object(), self = this;

    sendData.type = 'get';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Highscores.aspx",
        data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (respText) {
            self.renderScores(respText);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('An error occoured when getting the high scores');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion.. Why you don't try using done and fail instead of success, error. The other day I was playing around using success and it wasn't working properly when I was using timeout. I change to use done and fail and everything worked fine.

```
function getPartyIdName(partyId, isPrimary) {
    startDimScreen();
    var url = 'validateParty.html?partyId=' + partyId + '&isPrimary=' + isPrimary;
    $.ajax({url: url, context: document.body, timeout: 10000}).done(
        function (data) {
            stopDimScreen();
            handleResponse(data);
        }
    ).fail(
        function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus) {
                alert("An error has occurred:" + textStatus);
            }
            stopDimScreen();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok think i figured it out was just that my server wasn't returning JSON properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok think i figured it out was just that my server wasn't returning JSON properly.

Answer (score 0):

Some times After Returning the expected result also this error block will be executed sometime.

error:

```
function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert('An error occoured when getting the high scores');
}
```